# Can you make use of AOP with Ninject 2?

Tags: aop, ninject-2

I'm trying to find examples on the web of how to use AOP via Ninject. Can someone confirm if AOP is available in Ninject 2 without using external libraries (i.e. Castle Windsor?).

If it can be done, could you post a link to resources that would help me get started?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, use the Interception extension:

https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.interception

http://www.google.ch/search?client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-GB%3Aofficial&channel=s&hl=de&source=hp&biw=1330&bih=813&q=Ninject.Extensions.Interception&btnG=Google-Suche

Comment: Cheers for that. I'll check it out when I get time later this week. Much appreciated.

Comment: I'm in a bit of a muddle to be honest. Which version of the interception extnesions should I use - 2.0.1 or the RC 2 source for 2.1.0. I seem to have trouble building both i.e. not right version of Castle.Core referenced for example.